# Why is Grails plugin's BootStrap not executing?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, bootstrapping

I created a Grails plugin (`grails create-plugin myplugin1`) and noticed that there was no `myapp1/grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy` created like you normally get when you create a Grails app.

I created one like so:

```
class BootStrap {
    def init = {
        println("Hello! The plugin is bootstrapping...")
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

I then include the plugin with a Grails app (by adding `myplugin1` as a plugin inside the app's `BuildConfig.groovy`). When I issue a `grails run-app`, I don't see the above `println` ever executing.

Do Grails plugins not use `BootStrap.groovy`? If so, where should I put "bootstrap" code that needs to be executed when a plugin is loaded? Otherwise, if I was correct to do this above, why might I not be seeing the "*Hello! The plugin is bootstrapping...*" message print out?

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175587/2835520) worked for me, but its a Grails 3 issue. What Grails version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Plugin's BootStrap is EXCLUDED from the plugin package. You have to do your init-phase in the plugin descriptor, in one or several of the following closures:

```
def doWithSpring = {
  def appName = application.metadata.'app.name'
}

def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->
    // TODO Implement registering dynamic methods to classes (optional)
}

def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
    // TODO Implement post initialization spring config (optional)
}
```

Comment: Mind if we combine all our Answers into @injecteer's answer and delete ours? That way we have one solid answer to the question for future users?

Answer (score 2):

As always, start with the very well written and maintained [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/plugins.html).

Plugins do not include Bootstrap.groovy. The following are excluded from plugins (taken from documentation).

- grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy
- grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy (although it is used to generate dependencies.groovy)
- grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
- grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy (and any other *DataSource.groovy)
- grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy
- grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
- Everything within /web-app/WEB-INF
- Everything within /web-app/plugins/**
- Everything within /test/**
- SCM management files within **/.svn/** and **/CVS/**

In order to run code on startup of your plugin you need to hook into the runtime configuration of your plugin by using the `doWithSpring` or `doWithApplicationContext` (depending on what you need to do).

All of this, and more, is explained in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/plugins.html). An example might be:

```
// MyFancyPlugin.groovy
  ...
  def doWithApplicationContext = { appCtx ->
      def sessionFactory = appCtx.sessionFactory
      // do something here with session factory
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that needs to run at startup time should go in the `doWithApplicationContext` closure in the plugin descriptor (`MyPlugin1GrailsPlugin.groovy`).

Alternatively, call it something else (e.g. `MyPluginBootStrap.groovy`), as it's only the specific classes `BootStrap` and `UrlMappings` that are excluded when a plugin is packaged, but *any* class whose name ends `BootStrap` is considered a bootstrap artefact.

Comment: Mind if we combine all our Answers into @injecteer's answer and delete ours? That way we have one solid answer to the question for future users?